# Unable to find Franklin's last mission

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I've passed Mission #65 'Legal Trouble', but that's as far as I can go.
Franklin has one mission which is nowhere to be found. I took multiple cab rides, I called Tonya but she's busy, even though I've finished her missions as well. I can still switch between all people. When I call Trevor or Michael, they just say we have business to handle. All the night-races and parachuting are done as well.

Answer (score 1):

Once you finish [Legal Trouble](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Legal_Trouble) with Michael, a mission called [Meltdown](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Meltdown_(GTA_V)) should be unlocked for him **ONLY** if [Lamar Down](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Lamar_Down) has been completed.

This might be the mission that you are missing from Franklin to continue the history. You can start it from his mansion at [3671 Whispymound Drive](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/3671_Whispymound_Drive).